# OSStatus error 2003334207 AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play an audio url I get from the iTunes API. They are of type m4a. I save the URL as a string and send it to my playSound function. I have looked at other posts with this error but have not been able to fix mine.

example audio url

https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/Music1/v4/fd/4b/f9/fd4bf91e-2a1d-a946-a2f5-2d828da0f8e5/mzaf_2707169172634594413.plus.aac.p.m4a

I get an error "Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)"

```
func playSound(soundUrl: String) {
    let sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundUrl)
    do {
        let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound as URL)
        audioPlayer.delegate = self as? AVAudioPlayerDelegate
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I imagine the issue is with your initialization of `sound`. I believe you should have done `let sound = NSURL(string: soundUrl)`, not `let sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundUrl)`. fileURLWithPath creates an object from a local file, not from a remote file.